# how to create a form without max/min/close button in c#?

Tags: winforms, button

I know P/invoke can do, but is there a managed way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to toggle the [`ControlBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox.aspx) property.

```
public void CreateMyBorderlessWindow()
 {
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
    this.MinimizeBox = false;
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    // Remove the control box so the form will only display client area.
    this.ControlBox = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes... Just disable the control box on the form properties.